# How to mock package functions and interfaces that are internal to Go SDK?

Tags: go, gomock

I have limited experience with go and here I'm facing some challenges writing unit tests.

Initially, I had written something like,

```golang
type Pinger struct {
    sourceIP net.IP
    destIP   net.IP
    count    uint8
}

func (pinger *Pinger) resolveAddress(dest string) error {
    // some code
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:80")
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "error resolving outbound ip address of local machine")
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    pinger.sourceIP = conn.LocalAddr().(*net.UDPAddr).IP
    // more code
    // that resolves pinger.destIP
}

func (pinger *Pinger) Ping(host string) error {
    // some code
    if err := pinger.resolveAddress(host); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "error resolving source/destination addresses")
    }
    // more code
}
```

When I was writing unit tests, I got stuck at this line `conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:80")` because I was not sure how to mock or rightly handle this `net.Dial` call.

After searching online, I learned that such side-effect-inducing code should be put behind interfaces as

- that would decouple my high level logic from such operations(eg: `net.Dial`, `net.LookupIP`).
- and writing mocks (of interface methods) would get simpler. I can specify return value of `.EXPECT()` calls

##### So I made the following changes

1. Added an interface to abstract `net` related operations

```golang
type Pinger struct {
    // ...
    resolver AddressResolver // added this
}
```

added a new file `resolver.go` where I defined the interfaces and its methods

```golang
type AddressResolver interface {
    ResolveSource() (net.IP, error)
    ResolveDestination(dest string) (net.IP, error)
}

type LocalResolver struct{}

func (r *LocalResolver) ResolveSource() (net.IP, error) {
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:80")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    sourceIP := conn.LocalAddr().(*net.UDPAddr).IP
    return sourceIP, nil
}

func (r *LocalResolver) ResolveDestination(dest string) (net.IP, error) {
    var destIP net.IP

    ips, err := net.LookupIP(dest)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for _, ip := range ips {
        if ipv4 := ip.To4(); ipv4 != nil {
            destIP = ipv4
        }
    }
    return destIP, nil
}
```

2. Thus I achieved the decoupling of high-level logic from `net` calls.

```golang
func (pinger *Pinger) Ping(host string) error {
    // some code
    ip, err := pinger.resolver.ResolveSource()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "error resolving source address")
    }
    pinger.sourceIP = ip

    ip, err = pinger.resolver.ResolveDestination(host)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrapf(err, "error resolving destination address")
    }
    pinger.destIP = ip
    // more code
```

But this doesn't solve anything right? Yes, writing tests for `Ping` method got easier, but I will still have the same concern when I try to write tests for `resolver.go`. So essentially, I didn't solve the problem but rather hid it beneath a layer.

So my question is, how do I write test for the following part?

```
conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "8.8.8.8:80")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
defer conn.Close()
sourceIP := conn.LocalAddr().(*net.UDPAddr).IP
```

- Firstly, I don't know if I can mock this call because `net` is a package and not an interface.
- Secondly, I was expecting to receive some `fakeConn` type, on which I will write the expectations such as `fakeConn.EXPECT().Close()` but I don't know if I should be generating mocks for `net.Conn` interface as that's internal to SDK, I'm also not sure what value to pass to `-source` flag when I do mockgen`.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You cannot. Dead simple. Redesign your test(strategy).

Comment: That doesn't help, to be frank. If you could take some time to elaborate on the fallacy of my approach and what the right strategy looks like, that would be more helpful.

Comment: Either don’t test such stuff, make actual calls to some test server or test only the higher level of your code. ( I wouldn’t test this at all.)